# SQL SERVER 2012 SP1 don't accept external connections after upgrading Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, sql-server

I have several PCs working with SQL Server Express 2012 SP1 (11.0.3000) running with Windows 10 without problems. It Works with local connections and remote connections via IP (for example 10.11.12.13\SQLEXPRESS).

After the Windows 10 Aniversary Update or other auto update, it Works on local (including IP 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS and 10.11.12.13\SQLEXPRESS) but don't accept external connections.

- It happens on various servers, not only in one server.
- I checked the sme config with other working servers.
- All the services still running (SQL Server and Browser).
- The TCP configuration is correct and the same with other working servers.
- I have Firewall rules to allow remote connections to ports 1433 and 1434 with TCP and UDP.

I know about compatibility problems with SQL SERVER 2012 without Service Packs, but SP1 should be compatible.

Any suggestion?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This sounds like an Windows FW issue. Perhaps the rule in the FW that allows the connections internally need to be checked to confirm the "public" interface(s) to allow it thru at that level. A quick way to confirm whether or not it's Windows FW though is to completely disable it on all interfaces and then test. If it works with it disabled, then you know it's the FW to get the rules defined to allow the needed traffic.

Comment: I installed SQL 2014 and the problema persist. I checked firewall (deleted and created new rules). It seems to be a Domain Policy Problem. We still investigating.

Comment: Did you fix it? I have the same problem on two 2012R2 servers right now...

Comment: @Alenxander. At last is a problem with the domain security and network startup. In the "server" computer the network appears as "Not detected", then the firewall cut the external domain connections (all connections on this case). The problem is that the network card starts to slow (I thing). The solution, setup this computer to get the IP by DHCP and check the wall physical wire connections. It solved when the network appear as "Working network".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computers was under domain network, but in the network and sharing center it appears as "unknow network", then the firewall cuts all "external" connections.

If I change to "work network", it runs until restart.

I found two ways to solve it used in different cases:

1. Check physical wire connections (one case).
2. Get the computer IP by DHCP (several cases).

Hope it helps!